# Orientation Difference

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider two rotation matrices $\textbf{R}_A$, $\textbf{R}_B$. These matrices can be written as $\textbf{R} = [\textbf{e}_1\; \textbf{e}_2\; \textbf{e}_3]$ where $\textbf{e}_i$ are unit vectors.
I have seen a formula that states that the vector that describes the difference between the two orientations (which are described by the rotation matrices) is defined as:
$\frac{1}{2}(\textbf{e}_{A1}\times\textbf{e}_{B1}\;+\;\textbf{e}_{A2}\times\textbf{e}_{B2}\;+\textbf{e}_{A3}\times\textbf{e}_{B3}\;)$
I have never seen this formula before, does anyone know how this relation is extracted?
$\textbf{EDIT:}$ This formula is from an implementation for inverse kinamtics calcultion [code here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/robotics-toolbox-python/). In the transform.py file there is a function tr2diff that implements this equation. It is then used to calculate the difference between two orientations.

Comment: Could you tell us where you found this formula?

Comment: What is the meaning of the word orientation here?